# Stacking symbols

Tags: stacking-symbols

How could I stack two symbols on top of each other, so that they would appear smaller, i.e. something like `\begin{array}a\\b\end{array}`, but would fit nicely in a single line with the rest? So for example, I want to write `blah blah blah $S(\begin{array}a\\b\end{array})$ blah blah` in one single line.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `amsmath` has the `smallmatrix` environment for this.

Comment: @egreg The `smallmatrix` worked perfectly! Thanks pal! =)
@StevenB.Segletes - Thanks, I will wait for this! So far the small matrix suits my taste, but I am eager to also learn another method as you suggested with `stackengine`. Thanks a lot! =)

Comment: Related: [Matrix in small size](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58935/5764)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}

Default:% 3pt gap betwen glyphs
\(
c \stackanchor{$a$}{$b$} d
\)

Baselineskip gap:
\(
\def\stacktype{L}
c \stackanchor{$a$}{$b$} d
\)

Narrower vertical gap:
\(
c \stackanchor[1pt]{$a$}{$b$} d
\)

Bottom aligned:
\(
c \stackon{$a$}{$b$} d
\)

Top aligned:
\(
c \stackunder{$a$}{$b$} d
\)

Scriptsize:
\(
c \stackanchor{$\scriptstyle a$}{$\scriptstyle b$} d
\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. For now I just need the `smallmatrix` command. But I have to keep this, as I might (with high likelihood) use this as well.

Answer (score 5):

If it's only 2 symbols, there is a nice little, convenient hack:

```
$S(\smash{{}^a_b})$
```

Basically you create an empty group to attach the subscript and superscript to and then hack the height of the box containing them (practically reducing it to zero), so it won't interfere with the lines above or below.

This has the benefit of not requiring any package.

Use with caution! `:)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, upon comparing, I am more inclined to use `smallmatrix` as the natural spacing seems more suitable to what I am doing. =)