# How to generate row vector command from this code

Tags: fontsize, matrices

I found following code at [Matrix in small size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58935/matrix-in-small-size)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}
\newcommand{\colvec}[2][.8]{%
  \scalebox{#1}{%
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.8}%
    $\begin{bmatrix}#2\end{bmatrix}$%
  }
}

\begin{document}
\[
\mathbf{a}+\colvec{x\\y\\z}+\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}+\colvec[.7]{x\\y\\z}
\]
\end{document}
```

Right now I using

`\colvec[1]{1 \enskip \mathbf{q}^{T}}`

to write a row vector. But there must be a better way of doing this.

Comment: `\colvec{x&y&z}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `\colvec` just uses a manually scaled `bmatrix`, to make a row vector, one merely changes the `\\` separators to `&`, as in `\colvec{x&y&z}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}
\newcommand{\colvec}[2][.8]{%
  \scalebox{#1}{%
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.8}%
    $\begin{bmatrix}#2\end{bmatrix}$%
  }
}

\begin{document}
\[
\mathbf{a}+\colvec{x&y&z}^T+\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}+\colvec[.7]{x\\y\\z}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With a uniform syntax, so it's easy to change from `\rowvec` to `\colvec` by just changing the command:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\colvec}{O{0.8}m}
 {
  \scalebox{#1}{$\generalvec{#2}{\\}$}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\rowvec}{O{0.8}m}
 {
  \scalebox{#1}{$\generalvec{#2}{&}$}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\generalvec}{mm}
 {
  \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { #1 }
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.8}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \clist_use:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { #2 }
  \end{bmatrix}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\mathbf{a}+\rowvec{x,y,z}^T+\colvec{x,y,z}+\colvec[.7]{x,y,z}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]