# Align text in a new command

Tags: equations, align, matrices

So I've been looking to align text in a custom matrix that is already made smaller. See link below for reference.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59080/220808

In a \begin{pmatrix*} I'd simply put a [l] to align the numbers on the left, yet this is not that straight forward in a newcommand. Can somebody help me out?

I use this in my .sty file:

```
\newcommand{\colvec}[2][.8]{%
  \scalebox{#1}{%
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.8}%
    $\begin{bmatrix}#2\end{bmatrix}$%
  }
}
```

With in the Equation I use:

```
\colvec[0.9]{
      -8.6831 \times 10^{-2}&-2.4059 \times 10^{-4}&-3.7120&1.0337 \times 10^{-1}\\
      6.3872 \times 10^{-1}&4.5360 \times 10^{-3}&-2.4419 \times 10^{1}&3.7390 \times 10^{-1}\\
      -1.1624&-5.3189 \times 10^{-2}&-5.8483 \times 10^{1}&1.0665        
    }
```

The initial matrix would be:

```
\begin{pmatrix*}[l]
      -8.6831 \times 10^{-2}&-2.4059 \times 10^{-4}&-3.7120&1.0337 \times 10^{-1}\\
      6.3872 \times 10^{-1}&4.5360 \times 10^{-3}&-2.4419 \times 10^{1}&3.7390 \times 10^{-1}\\
      -1.1624&-5.3189 \times 10^{-2}&-5.8483 \times 10^{1}&1.0665        
\end{pmatrix*}
```

Comment: The standard `pmatrix` environment from `amsmath` does not accept an alignment specifier. If you are using `pmatrix* ` from `mathtools` please say so.

Comment: @campa I'm not sure what to use as I'm just trying out untill I see it working... Any suggestions on what to use? The matrix was that enormous that I had to add the colvec as opposed to reduce its size. I'm open for any other suggestion on how to improve it

Comment: My point is that you write "_In a `\begin{pmatrix}` I'd simply put a `[l]` to align the numbers on the left_" but that's not true unless you are doing something which you are not showing.

Comment: Updated it, you were right as i was using the pmatrix* instead :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to be able to control the alignment with a further optional argument, this is one possibility

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\colvec}[1][.8]{%
   \begingroup
   \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\def\@tempa{.8}\else\def\@tempa{#1}\fi
   \@colvec}

\newcommand{\@colvec}[2][c]{%
   \scalebox{\@tempa}{%
      \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.8}%
      $\begin{bmatrix*}[#1]#2\end{bmatrix*}$}%
      \endgroup}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\colvec{1\\-2\\3412}
\qquad
\colvec[][l]{1\\-2\\3412}
\qquad
\colvec[.6]{1\\-2\\3412}
\qquad
\colvec[.6][r]{1\\-2\\3412}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer! Is there an easy solution to solve the jump/mismatch when there is a minus sign just like in case 2? ```\hfill``` wont always do the job in that case unfortunately!

Comment: @Jasper I'm not sure I get it: would you like the numbers to be left-aligned and the minus sticking out farther to the left? That would be possible but is trickier...

Comment: Indeed thats exactly what id like to have, currently im using ```\hfill```, but i hope there is a way to automate that

Comment: @Jasper Uhm, as I said, possible but tricky, I have no time right now, maybe tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i appreciate the hulp thus far already :)