# side by side matrix, font sizing, and error message latex

Tags: math-mode, errors, matrices

```
\[
\colvec[1.7]{(-(1+\mathbf{J_{ee}})) & \mathbf{J_{ep}}& \mathbf{J_{es}}\\
\mathbf{J_{pe}} & -(1 + \mathbf{J_{pp}}) & -\mathbf{J_{ps}}\\
\mathbf{J_{se}} & -\mathbf{J_{sp}} & -(1 + \mathbf{J_{ss}})}\\
\colvec[1.7]{\hat{\bm{r_{e}}}\\
\hat{\bm{r_{p}}}\\ 
\hat{\bm{r_{s}}}}\\
\]
```

keeping getting an error: undefined control sequence and idk why

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}
\newcommand{\colvec}[2][.8]{%
  \scalebox{#1}{%
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.8}%
    $\begin{bmatrix}#2\end{bmatrix}$%
  }
}

\begin{document}
\title{Summer Project}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}

\maketitle

\[
\colvec[1.7]{(-(1+\mathbf{J_{ee}})) & \mathbf{J_{ep}}& \mathbf{J_{es}}\\
\mathbf{J_{pe}} & -(1 + \mathbf{J_{pp}}) & -\mathbf{J_{ps}}\\
\mathbf{J_{se}} & -\mathbf{J_{sp}} & -(1 + \mathbf{J_{ss}})}\\ 
\colvec[1.7]{\hat{\bm{r_{e}}}\\
\hat{\bm{r_{p}}}\\ 
\hat{\bm{r_{s}}}}\\

\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: please always post a complete small document that shows the problem. `\colvec` is not a command I recognise from any package so getting an undefined command error for that would not be unexpected.

Comment: The undefined command error does say which command is undefined, but you have not shown it.   If you have not loaded `bm` then `\bm` will be undefined.

Comment: you also appear to have `\\ ` at the top level inside `\[...\]` but `\[` is a single line math display, you can't use `\\ `

Comment: oh ok so then what do I use to separate the rows in the matrix?

Comment: I found the clov command because I couldn't figure out how to change the font size in the matrix any other way

Comment: you may have found it somewhere on the internet but how can we help if you don't say that. You still haven't said which command is undefined if it is `\bm` the answer is load `bm` package, if it is `\colvec` you need to say what you want it to do, then someone can suggest a definition.  You can use `\\ ` inside matrices but not at the top level of `\[`

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}
\newcommand{\colvec}[2][.8]{%
  \scalebox{#1}{%
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.8}%
    $\begin{bmatrix}#2\end{bmatrix}$%
  }
}

\begin{document}
\title{Summer Project}
\author{Robert Csete}
\date{\today}

\maketitle

\[
\colvec[1.7]{(-(1+\mathbf{J_{ee}})) & \mathbf{J_{ep}}& \mathbf{J_{es}}\\
\mathbf{J_{pe}} & -(1 + \mathbf{J_{pp}}) & -\mathbf{J_{ps}}\\
\mathbf{J_{se}} & -\mathbf{J_{sp}} & -(1 + \mathbf{J_{ss}})}\\
\colvec[1.7]{\hat{\bm{r_{e}}}\\
\hat{\bm{r_{p}}}\\ 
\hat{\bm{r_{s}}}}\\
\]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58935/matrix-in-small-size

Comment: that's where I found it

Comment: Well, as @DavidCarlisle pointed out twice you need to load the `bm` package you want to use the macro `\bm`.

Comment: @campa you forgot to say what an excellent package it is:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error from the posted document is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \bm 
                    
l.23 \hat{\bm{r_{s}}}}
                      \\
?
```

as you have not loaded `bm` to define `\bm`.

adding     \usepackage{bm}`

The error becomes

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.25 
     
?
```

as you can not have a blank line in math, deleting the line before `\]` it runs without error producing

[image]

But note that the `\\`  in your input are silently ignored as `\[` is always a single line display.

The spacing looks weirdly large as it is scaled up by 1.7 here (and latex then warns the display is too wide for the page) I would use a standard bmatrix

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}


\begin{document}
\title{Summer Project}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}

\maketitle

\[
\begin{bmatrix}
(-(1+\mathbf{J_{ee}})) & \mathbf{J_{ep}}& \mathbf{J_{es}}\\
\mathbf{J_{pe}} & -(1 + \mathbf{J_{pp}}) & -\mathbf{J_{ps}}\\
\mathbf{J_{se}} & -\mathbf{J_{sp}} & -(1 + \mathbf{J_{ss}})
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{\bm{r_{e}}}\\
\hat{\bm{r_{p}}}\\ 
\hat{\bm{r_{s}}}
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: probably I'd use `\hat{\bm{r}}_{\bm{e}}`  so the hat is over the r

Answer (score 3):

In addition to loading the `bm` package and reverting to using two `bmatrix` environments, as @DavidCarlisle does in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/603511/5001), I would also (a) place the `\hat` symbols solely above `\bm{r}` and (b) not boldface the subscript terms.

[image]

I must confess to not understanding why the `J` terms are rendered in **bold upright** math (via `\mathbf`) whereas the `r` terms are rendered in ***bold italic*** math (via `\bm`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
-(1+\mathbf{J}_{ee}) & \mathbf{J}_{ep}        & \mathbf{J}_{es}  \\
\mathbf{J}_{pe}      & -(1 + \mathbf{J}_{pp}) & -\mathbf{J}_{ps} \\
\mathbf{J}_{se}      & -\mathbf{J}_{sp}       & -(1 + \mathbf{J}_{ss}) 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{\bm{r}}_{e} \\
\hat{\bm{r}}_{p} \\ 
\hat{\bm{r}}_{s}
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```